# Visual Studio 2017 and project from GitHub or Visual Studio Team Services

Tags: github, visual-studio-2017

I have several projects on GitHub and on Visual Studio Team Services. In VS 2015 I simply connected to a server, selected and connected to a project. In Team Explorer I saw all solutions in Solution part. In Visual Studio 2017 I don't see any solution. If I check it again in VS 2015 (on the same computer), it works fine. Is there something more to do in VS 2017 to see the solutions in Solutions part?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tried to find where I read this yesterday but I can't remember, but according to Microsoft on the developer forums, this is as intended.  You need to click "show folder view" to see your solution.

Comment: It seems I found it: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/2733/solutions-not-shown-in-team-explorer.html It doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: @SlávekRydval Since it is not a bug and Visual Studio team are working on transitioning the services formerly provided by the Solution section in Team Explorer to the new “AnyCode” support provided by the Solution Explorer. You can track the update of VS.

Comment: @SlávekRydval yeah I don't get it either.

Comment: Microsoft is getting it back: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/04/18/visual-studio-2017-preview-15-2/

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be using TFVC for this example.

Have you defined a workspace – or at least looked at the workspace in Source Code Explorer – so VS2017 knows you have the local files?

(AIUI the solutions list is based on a search of the local workspace.)

Comment: Same happens to me and I'm using Git.

Comment: Yes, Workspace is defined, files are on the disk in the right folder. Source Code Explorer shows everything right. I can open a solution, build it, run it.